# Using wget to retrieve files from autostart downloads

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, downloads, autostart, wget

So I'm making my own document of codes to run after a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 and I want to try and keep everything in the command line (as opposed to having to open a browser to download files).

So I've got

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
```

for downloading google chrome and wanted to make something similar for Opera, so I have this link to download the opera browser .deb install file

www.opera.com/download/get/?id=35889&location=360&nothanks=yes&sub=marine

and have tried a variety of different things with wget but I can't seem to get it to download the .deb file. I would really like to do this from the command line instead of opening a browser to download the file.

Thanks.

Comment: It downloaded fine for me. You didn't describe what happened when you tried it, did you get an error? could you add that to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
wget -Oopera.deb 'www.opera.com/download/get/?id=35889&location=360&nothanks=yes&sub=marine'
```

works for me. The `-Oopera.deb` option is requried otherwise the filename will be `index.html?id=35889&location=360&nothanks=yes&sub=marine`.
It downloads it into a file called `opera.deb`

Answer (score 1):

Well for me it worked.

But you can get the direct link if you want, the problem is how to have always the latest version.

I got the direct link using firebug in firefox.
You need to install the add-on and then enable the net panel:
[image]

Then you past the link you gave us in the browser and you will see all the details in firebug, from which you only need to copy the link (look at the one that has the correct size).

[image]

The result being:

http://get.geo.opera.com/pub/opera/linux/1216/opera_12.16.1860_amd64.deb